# Creating uncompressed video files from sequences of images with partial looping

Tags: ffmpeg

I have multiple sequences of 7 images. I would like to encode these 7 images into a 10 fps video file that cycles through the first 4 images in the first 4 frames, and then repeats the rest of the images in a looping order for a total of n frames. For example, a 32-frame video file as follows:

12345676567656765676567656765676

Is there a way to predetermine the order of the 7 frames, including duplicates (the repetition of images 5, 6, and 7)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the desired sequence `1234 5676 5676 5676 5676 5676 5676 5676`, which can be achieved using a combination of filters.

`ffmpeg -framerate 10 -i %d.png -vf "split=2[head][loop];[head]trim=end_frame=4[head];[loop]trim=start_frame=3,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,loop=6:4:0,shuffleframes=1 2 3 2[tail];[head][tail]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0" out.mp4`

Comment: One more question if I may--I have a folder full of a ton of images. They are all named accordingly so they are in those groups of 7 right next to each other in the list. Is there a way to modify the command so I can run it once in the directory and it will create each video file for each group of 7? There's hundreds of these groups.

Comment: That's a shell/batch scripting Q, not part of ffmpeg's domain.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again!