# Batch execute (ffmpeg) command on multiple sets of images at once [Novice]

Tags: python, cmd, ffmpeg, batch-processing

I'm relatively new to navigating Python libraries, Windows batch processing, and coding as a whole. Here is my situation:

I have multiple folders each with n images in them, where n is a number divisible by 7.
In each folder, the images are in sets of 7, grouped by their name. If one set of these images was named "apple", I would have the following seven images with the following naming structure:

`Apple.0_aspect-gigapixel-art-scale-4_00x.png,`
`Apple.1_aspect-gigapixel-art-scale-4_00x.png,`
`Apple.2_aspect-gigapixel-art-scale-4_00x.png,`
`Apple.3_aspect-gigapixel-art-scale-4_00x.png,`
`Apple.4_aspect-gigapixel-art-scale-4_00x.png,`
`Apple.5_aspect-gigapixel-art-scale-4_00x.png`
`Apple_aspect-gigapixel-art-scale-4_00x.png`
(Please note that that order matters, the numberless file should be the last, but if the files are sorted by alphabetical/date, that *should already* be the case.)

For each one of these sets of images inside of one of the folders, I am using ffmpeg to make a video file with the guidelines outlined in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69229903/creating-uncompressed-video-files-from-sequences-of-images-with-partial-looping). On that post I received great help from  the user Gyan, who gave me this command: `ffmpeg -framerate 10 -i %d.png -vf "split=2[head][loop];[head]trim=end_frame=4[head];[loop]trim=start_frame=3,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,loop=6:4:0,shuffleframes=1 2 3 2[tail];[head][tail]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0" out.mp4`. I am wanting to batch execute this command in each of my folders of images, having it create a video file for each one of the groups of 7.

TLDR; How can I batch execute a ffmpeg command (above) on multiple sets of images at once?

Thank you all so much. I very much appreciate the help I've received so far.

Comment: Is the grouping always on the prefix?  So, {prefix}.{count}_aspect-etc.png?

Answer (score 0):

This will print the command lines to stdout.  You can capture those to a batch file and run it (`python script.py > runit.bat`).  The principle here is to have a template string, and then fill in the pieces of the template.  I assume that every new sequence starts with a ".0" file.  This names the output file the same as the final input file (the one without a digit), with .mp4 added.

```
import os

command = 'ffmpeg -framerate 10 -i {root}/{nums} -i {root}/{final}.png -vf "split=2[head][loop];[head]trim=end_frame=4[head];[loop]trim=start_frame=3,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,loop=6:4:0,shuffleframes=1 2 3 2[tail];[head][tail]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0" {root}/{out}.mp4'

startpath = 'x'

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(startpath):
    files.sort()
    for file in files:
        pfx = file.find('.0')
        if pfx < 0:
            continue
        prefix = file[:pfx]
        pattern = file.replace('.0','.%d')
        final = file.replace('.0','')[:-3]
        print( command.format( root=root, nums=pattern, final=final, out=final ) )
```

Comment: Hi Tim. When you say "template string", I'm unsure what you mean. Am I making a template string for each one of the groups of 7? And yes, every new first image in a sequence starts with a ".0". I tried to capture the stdout of the script to a text file for testing, but I found that doing this overwrote whatever was in the test file and made it blank.

Comment: What I call "command" there is a template; it has the guts of the command with fields to be filled in.  If you want to APPEND this to a batch, then use `python script.py >> runit.bat`.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. So what am I changing inside of your script so when executed in a folder with multiple sets it prints the ffmpeg command for each of my sets of 7 to stdout?

Comment: Yes, it prints ALL of the ffmpeg commands to stdout.  It doesn't have to 7 per set, as long as it follows the pattern.

Comment: I don't see where my format of [setName].[0-5]_aspect-gigapixel-art-scale-4_00x.png for all images besides last in the set and [setName]_aspect-gigapixel-art-scale-4_00x.png for the last the set is specified.

Comment: I process all files in the folder.  If the filename contains ".0", then it is the start of a new subset.  I don't really care how many are in the set, I just create `ffmpeg` command and ignore everything else until there is another ".0".  The "%d" in the command means that `ffmpeg` will take care of reading the parts.